# Is DNS Caching in production recommended?

Tags: domain-name-system, cache

We are using a cloud provider (AWS) and using their DNS servers. Is it advisable to use `nscd`, `dnsmasq` or `pdnsd` to create a local dns cache on each server? There are a couple of posts calling `nscd` buggy.

Comment: I guess this depends on the application, it's requirements and capabilities. JRE for example has a small Resolver cache. Some apps might want to talk to a DNS server directly. I had no problems with keeping nscd enabled on distributions which installed It by default.

Comment: Depends how worried you are about the amount of requests, I can't imagine if you're running normal TTLs (~24h) that the traffic would be significant enough to decrease app performance or incur latency or extra costs..

Comment: nscd is a problem if you are using nfs and have more than 16 groups associated with users or files/dirs.  it is a legit issue that will not likely ever be fixed.  long story, many old mailing lists, etc..

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get benefits of DNSSEC, you are more or less forced to run your own local recursive nameserver. You can have a look at `unbound`.

Answer (score 0):

Cases where caching should be enabled are numerous. I'd say first it depends on the roles you plan to deploy on your servers. Be careful about DNS poisoning, time-to-live parameter which defines when DNS entries are forcefully updated.
Caching is always a quite good thing but might expose your infrastructure to failures or errors.
On a basis, only enable DNS caching on server which really needs to resolve quickly their requests.